# Factorygirl Admin Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, admin

I am following Michael Hartl's online tutorial and in Listing 9.42, I am having trouble comprehending the code.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
end
```

Then admin is created in listing 9.43

```
  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
```

What I don't understand is how that is possible to create an admin without any 
code of

```
   sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
```

inside the admin block?

It seems :admin block is nested inside :user block and so the :user block code is executed during `FactoryGirl.create(:admin)` creating an admin with users name, email, password inside the :user block?

Is that right?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you already know how [FactoryGirl library works](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), the explanation to your question is that the `:admin` factory is defined inside the `:user` factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, `:admin` will inherit all the properties of the user, plus the specific `admin: true` setting.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.  When you create a nested FactoryGirl object, that object inherits all attributes of its parent.