# Factory Girl not initiating secondary object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot, bdd, rspec3

I have two Factory Girl objects on a single file.

**spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
     first_name "Charlie"
     last_name "Brown"
     email "email@example.com"
     password "charbar1234"
     password_confirmation "charbar1234"
  end

  factory :admin do
    first_name "Bob"
    last_name "Marley"
    email "bob@marley.com"
    password "bobmarley1234"
    password_confirmation "bobmarley1234"
    admin true
  end
end
```

When I call `create(:user)`, my test runs fine. When I call `create(:admin)`, I get the following error...

```
Failures:

  1) admin accesses the database
     Failure/Error: create(:admin)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Admin
     # ./spec/features/admins/admin_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the test..

**spec/features/admins/admin_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "admin" do
    it 'accesses the database' do
        create(:admin)
        visit root_path
        click_link "Log In"
        fill_in "Email", with: "bob@marley.com"
        fill_in "Password", with: "bobmarley1234"
        click_button "Log In"

        expect(current_path).to eq(admin_dashboard_path)
        with 'h1' do
            expect(page).to have_content 'Administration'
        end
        expect(page).to have_content 'Manage Users'
        expect(page).to have_content 'Manage Articles'
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have an Admin model?

Comment: No, maybe I'm misunderstanding how Factory Girl's syntax works..

Comment: Ok, if that's the case see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `factory :admin` inside of the `factory :user`.

It should look something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
end
```

See [Factorygirl Admin Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911138/factorygirl-admin-creation)

Comment: Oh I see! That works out great and the link was also very helpful. Thank you!